# Data Annotation Validators with the Entity Framework MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following View, Controller and Comment.cs code, but I get an error,

**The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'TMPBlog.Models.Comment', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'TMPBlog.Models.Post'.**

If I don’t enter any text into the two required text fields **@Html.TextBox("CommentEmail")** and **@Html.TextArea("CommentDetail", new { cols = "65", rows = "7" })**, if I do it works fine.

**Controller code,**

```
public ActionResult Index(int PostID)
{
    Post post = db.Posts.Single(p => p.PostID == PostID);
    return View(post);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Comment comment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string CommentEmail = comment.CommentEmail;

        string CommentDetail = comment.CommentDetail;
        CommentDetail = CommentDetail.Replace("\n", "<br />");
        comment.CommentDetail = CommentDetail;

        db.Comments.AddObject(comment);
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("CommentResponse", new { id = comment.CommentID });
    }
    return View(comment);
}
```

**Comment.cs,**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace TMPBlog.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(CommentMetaData))]
    public partial class Comment
    {
    }

    public class CommentMetaData
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must enter an email address!")]
        public object CommentEmail { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public object CommentDetail { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**View,**

```
@model TMPBlog.Models.Post

@Html.ValidationSummary("There is an error")

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.Hidden("CommentDate", String.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}", DateTime.Now))
    @Html.Hidden("PostCommentFK", @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostID))

    <br />
    <span class="BlueHeading">Add Your Comments Here!</span>
    <br /><br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        Email Address
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("CommentEmail")
        @Html.ValidationMessage("CommentEmail", "*")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        Comments
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextArea("CommentDetail", new { cols = "65", rows = "7" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("CommentDetail", "*")
    </div>

    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.CheckBox("CommentTicked") Email me when others comment
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Add Comment" />
    </p>
}
```

How do I solve this?

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is strongly typed to `TMPBlog.Models.Post`, but in your POST controller action you are passing a comment:

```
return View(comment);
```

This obviously is wrong.

You could simply return the same view:

```
return View();
```

Since everything is stored in the modelstate the view will be correctly redisplayed with the corresponding error messages.

Also the following line:

```
@Html.Hidden("PostCommentFK", @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostID))
```

could probably be simplified:

```
@Html.Hidden("PostCommentFK", Model.PostID)
```

Comment: Darin, thank you, you are a champion! I come from way back, programming in C, I’ve been through Classic, Webforms and now MVC. I guess my problem is these days is I can’t get my head around how easy this stuff is and therefore look way to deeply into it. I can’t believe it was that simple! Even the error responses just work! Love this new world! Cheers,